# Trying to make a wrapper for a property that should adjust a string

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift4, swift5

I have this code that I need to make reusable by other apps.

This code shows messages where the localized app's name is present.

So, I have localized strings like this:

```
"DoYou" = "Do you really want to close $$$?";
"Quit" = "Quit $$$";
"Keep Running" = "Keep $$$ Running";
```

Where `$$$` must be replaced with the localized app's name at run time.

Because I want to learn about property wrappers, I have tried to create this one:

```
extension String {

  func findReplace(_ target: String, withString: String) -> String
  {
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: target,
                                     with: withString,
                                     options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal,
                                     range: nil)
  }
}


  @propertyWrapper
  struct AdjustTextWithAppName<String> {
    private var value: String?


    init(wrappedValue: String?) {
      self.value = wrappedValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: String? {
      get { value }
      set {
        if let localizedAppName = Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
          let replaced = value.findReplace("$$$", withString: localizedAppName)

        }
        value = nil
      }
    }

  }
```

I get this error on the `replaced` line:

> Value of type String? has no name `findReplace`

I have also tried to use this line

```
 let replaced = value!.findReplace("$$$", withString: localizedAppName)
```

Same error...

---

The string may contain the app's name more than once. This is why I have that extension to `String`.

Comment: Your function doesn't match the call to it, you need to replace `findReplace(target: String, withString: String)` with `findReplace(_ target: String, withString: String)`

Comment: @Maximilian - sorry that was a typo. Just did that and the error persists.

Comment: The built-in localization system already has support for placeholders like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this your property wrapper can't have a genereic type named String because that shadows the built-in type String that your extension belongs to. So change the `struct` declaration to not be generic

```
@propertyWrapper
struct AdjustTextWithAppName {
```

or name the type to something else

```
@propertyWrapper
struct AdjustTextWithAppName<T> {
```

and fix the `set` method

```
set {
    guard let str = newValue, let localizedAppName = Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String else {
        value = nil
     } 

     value = str.findReplace(target: "$$$", withString: localizedAppName)
  }
```

Comment: Value of type 'String' has no member 'findReplace' at your last line

Comment: @SpaceDog Works fine for me, did you change the declaration?

Comment: you mean, change the struct line and the set block? yes. What do you mean my wrapper can't be generic?

Comment: ah, I see, a return is needed inside the guard. Now it is compiling well. Thanks. Can you explain why mine was not working? Thanks

Comment: @SpaceDog Your generic parameter `String` conflicted with the definition of `Swift.String` in the wrapper scope.

Comment: @Maximilian, Thanks, I just updated my answer with this. My previous explanation wasn't correct.